# Documentation for version 4-11.4 of material ui is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Since the rollout of MUI v5.0.0-rc.1 all the doc pages of v4 other than v4.12.3 seem to have disappeared.

https://mui.com/versions/

and

https://v4-11-4.material-ui.com/  (now broken)

where can I find the previous versions documentations  ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be related: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28368

You can get the previous versions from git.

Clone the branch with the version you want

```
git clone --single-branch --branch v4.11.4 https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui.git
```

Then cd to the folder

```
cd material-ui
```

Run it as dev (faster but has to compile individual pages)

```
yarn && yarn docs:dev
```

Or build and start it (a bit slower but worth it)

```
yarn && yarn docs:build && yarn docs:start
```

Then access it in `http://localhost:3000/`

You must use yarn, `npm install --global yarn` if you don't have it

Comment: Darn, thank you, I will give it a try !

Answer (score 5):

You can find old documentation here:

https://v4.mui.com/

Comment: Nevermind, I suppose I didn't read whole question through.

Comment: If that is the case, you should go ahead and just delete the answer.